# Reprogramming MCU Flash Memory I/O placed on a PCB of a mechanical keyboard

Tags: microcontroller, pcb, keyboard

I've decided to modify some things about my mechanical keyboard (Hermes M1), so I tough starting with installing the software driver it's a good idea. Thus I've changed some things about lighting of it and stuff, until I've come to MACRO submenu of the software, and the software crashed.

The problem that the keyboard has in its memory now is that the layout is all messed up, for example if i press: **ASDF** on a normal keyboard, on this broken one it leads to : **AFJ:** , and so on, all of it, only few key match, I cannot start the software of the device, because it crashes.

So.. I've decided to fix it, the "complicated" way, my toughs are that somehow i can hard reset all the memory that is stored in its MCU, I've tried something with *DFU-Util*, but no succes (i don't know if it's the best soft to do this), i've looked up at *Renesas Flash Programmer*, but aswell no succes.

Here's some photos with the back of it:
[image: whole back]
[image: MCU and model]

The model of the MCU is HT68FB560, and from their website it is an I/O Flash USB MCU with SPI ([their website](https://www.holtek.com/productdetail?p_p_auth=q0FpqQ4D&p_p_id=productvgpageportlet_WAR_holtekprodportlet&p_p_lifecycle=0&p_p_state=maximized&p_p_mode=view&_productvgpageportlet_WAR_holtekprodportlet_virtualGroupId=318)), so is it a way to reset all their software settings from that MCU? All the opinions are well received. I have to mention that before this the keyboard didn't have any problem, and all the circuits from PCB are well connected.

Comment: Even if you can erase the flash, that will also erase the program it's running and render your keyboard entirely useless.

Comment: That software is exclusively optional in order for keyboard to run it, so no, you can always plug it in any computer and run it with the settings set stored inside it. EDIT: yes, that's true, so, is there any basic setup in order for a PCB of a keyboard to work??

Comment: No, I mean it will erase the keyboard's firmware that it needs to communicate with the computer.

Comment: Keyboard PCBs are not universal. If you can upgrade/reset the firmware at all is very manufacturer dependant. The software to do this will also be chip or manufacturer specific depending on how the manufacturer implemented the boot loader.

Comment: Try installing it on an old computer running Windows XP or vista.

Comment: Yeah @RonBeyer , I've used this strategy with 2 keyboards, also which soft would you suggent to try to reset firmware?

Comment: BTW, you can hook multiple keyboards to your computer if you need to be able to type while the messed up one is connected... If you don't have another one, you can use the on screen keyboard (assuming windows this is osk.exe).

Comment: I can't suggest any, you need to contact the manufacturer, there may not be any available, that's my point.

Comment: @BruceAbbott I'll try that aswell, but it might be the same.

Comment: @RonBeyer Uh... found this, that why this mini project it was a hope for me: https://github.com/ruiqimao/keyboard-pcb-guide ,  (the bad part of that tutorial is that the guy is using a 44 pins  MCU, and I have a 48 pins ) but yeah, maybe is without any results all of this

Comment: Again, that's a specific keyboard, it's not universal. It's specifically designed to be programmed. The manufacturer of your keyboard may have that disabled, or only available from a specialized software they don't give out. Even if you could reflash it, you need a copy of thier firmware to flash.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and clarify what you did exactly. I don't get what you did. Is it the OS's driver software you messed up, did you already flash something on the keyboard, what exactly do you mean by "software of the device"? Does the OS's driver crash, or the keyboard's firmware? Did you try the keyboard with another PC? What does the keyboard's manual say about resetting all?

Comment: "my toughs are that somehow i can hard reset all the memory that is stored in its MCU" Reset to _what_? You don't have the original binary and the manufacturer sure as s*** won't give it to you. This is nonsense - you clearly have no idea what you are doing. Buy a new keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

If DFU mode doesn't work, it looks like you need [a special in-circuit programmer](https://www.holtek.com/e-writerpro).

[image]
[image]